# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "account_program" does not exist LINE 1: ...ated_date", "account_program"."updated_date" FROM "account_p

Tags: python, django

I am using Django 2.0.8 and using postgres DB. It was working fine when I started working on this project. I am facing this issue after uploading to heroku. I see this error when I run the code on my local database and the same code runs perfectly without issue on heroku DB.

*projectname/settings.py*

```
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'account.apps.AccountConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.postgres',
    'wagtail.contrib.forms',
    'wagtail.contrib.redirects',
    'wagtail.embeds',
    'wagtail.sites',
    'wagtail.users',
    'wagtail.snippets',
    'wagtail.documents',
    'wagtail.images',
    'wagtail.search',
    'wagtail.admin',
    'wagtail.core',
    'modelcluster',
    'taggit',
    'empoweru',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'wagtail.core.middleware.SiteMiddleware',
    'wagtail.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectMiddleware',
]
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'dbanme',
        'USER': 'dbuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'dbpassword',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

*Error*

```
C:\Users\nikes\Desktop\Version - 6\empoweru>python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "account_program" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ated_date", "account_program"."updated_date" FROM "account_p...
                                                             ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 332, in execute
    self.check()
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 351, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 73, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 399, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 540, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 533, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Desktop\Version - 6\empoweru\empoweru\urls.py", line 26, in <module>
    path('account/', include('account.urls')),
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Desktop\Version - 6\empoweru\account\urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Desktop\Version - 6\empoweru\account\views.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .forms import LoginForm, UserEditForm, ProfileEditForm, ProgramForm, UploadFileForm
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Desktop\Version - 6\empoweru\account\forms.py", line 14, in <module>
    class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Desktop\Version - 6\empoweru\account\forms.py", line 18, in UploadFileForm
    for program in Program.objects.all().order_by('program_name'):
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 272, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1179, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1068, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "account_program" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ated_date", "account_program"."updated_date" FROM "account_p...


                                                        ^

                                                             ^
```

*account/model.py*

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

# Create your models here.

class Program(models.Model):
    #program_id = models.AutoField(null=False, primary_key=True)
    program_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False)
    program_start_date = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False)
    program_end_date = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    def created(self):
        self.created_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def updated(self):
        self.updated_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.program_name)
```

Comment: Have you applied all the migrations?

Comment: Sorry Mohit, I didn't understand your comment. I dont see any files in migrations. I get this error when I run "python manage.py makemigrations"

Comment: @Nik  are you sure you are getting that error while running "python manage.py makemigrations"  because traceback says otherwise

Comment: @sky_1 Yes the errors are displayed when I run makemigrations. I have updated the error code with the command

Answer (score 1):

it is because you have to add your account app to the installed app list to create migrations for that just add account to your installed app and run`python manage.py makemigrations` to create migrations for account app and then migrate it to database by running `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: When I add account to INSTALLED_APPS I see a different error like mentioned below.  

 File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 347, in execute
    django.setup()  
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)  
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 93, in populate
    "duplicates: %s" % app_config.label)  
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't unique, duplicates: account

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with my migration files, after deleting the migration file I tried to migrate and I still see the same issue, so I created my initial migration file and it worked.

The initial(0001_initial.py) file looked like the one below.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion
import django.utils.timezone


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Program',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('program_name', models.CharField(max_length=20)),
            ('program_start_date', models.DateField()),
            ('program_end_date', models.DateField()),
            ('created_date', models.DateTimeField(blank=True, default=django.utils.timezone.now)),
            ('updated_date', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)),
        ],
    ),
]
```